# how add in this array all values? it's everytime create a new CLIENT array and push value to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
this.state = {
  CLIENT: []
}

handleChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    CLIENT: [value]
  });
};
```

How to add the current value to the previous values, and not replace them.

After adding a value to `CLIENT = [value1,value2]`, I want it to be `CLIENT = [value1,value2, value3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat or spread the previous CLIENT state to the new state:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    CLIENT: [...prevState.CLIENT, value]
  }));
};
```